# Laravel handling 404 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am handling 404 error and redirecting to custom 404 error page on Laravel using following in route

```
App::error(function(Exception $e) {
return Redirect::route('404'); });
```

This works well in most of the cases expect one.

It doesn't work in the following case where user puts / in the end of URL

eg. **localhost/laravel/public/somehting** goes to custom 404 page

but **localhost/laravel/public/something/** goes to Apache default 404 error page

I am testing this on windows(local) using wamp

Do i need to make some changes to .htaccess file or can i solve this problem from route itself.

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file and your Laravel route definitions. There's no way to guess where the error comes from without the code responsible for the routing.

Comment: The .htaccess should remove the trailing `/`, `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` does that not happen in your system?

Comment: thanks I haven't tried it yet. I will try  now

Comment: still the same even on a live server